# Display operations on multiple fractions in a single line

Tags: java, fractions

The following code is working as expected, however I'm unable to display the output on a single line. All numbers are **random numbers** printed using **`Random() function.`**

> **As of now, it's printing like this:**

```
38 
--- + 
45 
90 
--- + 
16 
29 
--- + 
21 
54 
--- + 
99 


=   211 
    --- 
    181
```

> **The output should be displayed like this:**

```
38      90       29     54     211
--- +  ----  +  ---- + ---- = ----- 
45      16       21     99     181
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FractionJava2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Array to store Numerator variables */
        int[] num =  new int[4];

        /* Array to store Denominator variables */
        int [] denom = new int[4];

        /* Variable to hold the operator sign */
        char ch ;

        /* Random function to get the random numbers */
        Random random = new Random();

        /* Scanner function to take the user input */
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num_sum[] = new int[num.length];
        int denom_sum[] = new int[denom.length]; 


        for (int i = 0, j=0; i < denom.length; i++, j++) {

            num[i] = random.nextInt(100)+1;
            denom[j]=random.nextInt(100)+1;

            System.out.println("Numerators are: " +num[i]);
            System.out.println("Denominators are: "+denom[i]); 
        }


            System.out.println("Enter the operation you wish to perform");
            ch = scan.next().toCharArray()[0];

            System.out.println("\nThe resultant fraction is: ");

        /* Variable to hold the sum of numerator values */
        int numeratorSum = 0;

        /* Variable to hold the sum of denominator values */
        int denominatorSum = 0;


        switch(ch){

        case '+' : 


                for (int i = 0; i < denom_sum.length; i++) {

                    num_sum[i] = num_sum[i] + num[i];
                    denom_sum[i] = denom_sum[i]+ denom[i];

                    System.out.printf("%d \n", num_sum[i]);
                    System.out.printf("--- %c \n", ch);
                    System.out.printf("%d \n", denom_sum[i]);

                    numeratorSum = numeratorSum + num_sum[i];
                    denominatorSum = denominatorSum + denom_sum[i];
            }
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.printf("=\t");
                System.out.printf("%d \n", numeratorSum);
                System.out.printf("\t--- \n", ch);
                System.out.printf("\t%d ", denominatorSum);

    }
  }
}
```

> **I'm unable to trace out, as to what is preventing from printing the desired output.**
>   **Please help !!!**

Comment: you are using `println`, which adds a line feed every time you call it; try using `print`

Comment: @DaveBennett - Which part of the code are you trying to point out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need multiple loops, one for each output line :

```
            // first line
            for (int i = 0; i < denom_sum.length; i++) {
                num_sum[i] = num_sum[i] + num[i];
                System.out.printf("%d   ", num_sum[i]);
                numeratorSum = numeratorSum + num_sum[i];
            }
            System.out.printf("     %d \n", numeratorSum);
            // second line
            for (int i = 0; i < denom_sum.length; i++) {
                System.out.printf("--- %c", ch);
            }
            System.out.printf("=\t   --- \n", ch);
            // third line
            for (int i = 0; i < denom_sum.length; i++) {
                denom_sum[i] = denom_sum[i]+ denom[i];                    
                System.out.printf("%d    ", denom_sum[i]);
                denominatorSum = denominatorSum + denom_sum[i];
            }
            System.out.printf("\t%d \n", denominatorSum);
```

I probably got the spaces and TABs wrong, but you get the idea.

BTW, your output is incorrect. That's not how you add fractions.

Comment: **`Thank you for your quick response.`** I understand that adding of fractions would require to find the LCM of the denominator & proceed further.  However, I wasn't aiming for the actual addition of fractions as you are pointing out.  Although the number might be in the form of fraction, but the addition remains as if we are adding a number ignoring the fractional part of it.

Comment: **`BTW, your code worked like a magic !!  If supposing I were to add the fractions the normal way, what changes are required in the code ..`**
A simple tip should do the needful.

Comment: @mindfreak That would require a decent amount of changes to your code. That being said, why would you want to add fractions the normal way when that is not what your program intends to do?

Comment: @ChetanKinger - **`#JustAsking`**  As the saying goes "Self-help is the best help", would slog it out myself to find an answer. **If at all, am stuck anywhere would need to jump in here to find the experts help.**

Comment: @mindfreak Yes but you need to make up your mind. When Eran pointed out that that's not the way fractions are added, you said you weren't aiming for actual addition of fractions. Now you want exactly the opposite. Post a new question as the answer cannot be covered in comments.

Comment: @ChetanKinger - What I was looking out for, was already answered by Eran at the first go. Since Eran pointed out the flaw in the output considering the original way of adding fraction, I thought may be in that process if I get some tip flowing from his end, I would get that part done as well. **`Human tendency of wanting more, nothing else !!`**  Anyways, thanks for your concern...